# vue3 composition api script setup, share click event with other components

Tags: vuejs3, composition, composable

I am using Vue3 (composition API with script setup) and I am trying to share a click event with other components.

```
<h1 @click="useLink">Header #</h1>
```

```
        const useLink = (e) => {
            let section = e.target.closest(".section");
    
            if (router.currentRoute.value.hash !== "#" + section.id) {
                router.push("#" + section.id);
            }
        };
```

Note: This method is repeated in few other components. ☹️

When a user clicks on h1, useLink() gets called and pushes that id to router which scrolls to position.

Thanks

Comment: You question is not clear. What does not work as expected? What is your problem? Please clarify!

Answer (score 1):

A composable should export a function that returns some reusable logic (in this case, another function)

**link.js**

```js
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export function useLink() {
  const router = useRouter();

  function goToSection(e) {
    const section = e.target.closest('.section');

    if (router.currentRoute.value.hash !== '#' + section.id) {
      router.push('#' + section.id);
    }
  }
  return {
    goToSection
  };
}
```

Then in any component you need this reusable function: import the file, destructure the reusable function, and apply it to your `@click` handlers.

**component.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { useLink } from '@/composables/link';

const { goToSection } = useLink();
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="section" id="one">
    .
    .
    .
    <h1 @click="goToSection">Scroll to section div</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```